# Handling Generated Files in Puppet

Tags: windows, puppet

Lets say I have an exec resource on a node that creates a file with a name determined at run time. I have full access to the script being run, and the script knows the name of the file it is creating.

In Puppet, preferably without using that much raw ruby, how can I use the name of this file that was created in a File or Package resource?

From what I have seen some people have mentioned using a custom fact for this. However if I intend to use the same script multiple times, how do I keep the fact isolated in the correct scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might prove more difficult than it appears.

Generally, a fact is a good way to get information from the agent to the master. With Facter `2.x` the fact can take an array or hash value to accomodate multiple file names that you wish to communicate.

However, the manifest can *never* rely on a value that is determined during the synchronization of an `exec` (or any) resource. That's because the resources are evaluated during the catalog application phase. This phase begins after manifest compilation is complete. The agent works with a complete catalog. Fact information is gathered before compilation even starts. So the manifest must be able to fully rely on information that is present before the compiler starts evaluating it.

Note that this is no different if you use `puppet apply` instead of master/agent.

I can see two way for you to go about this.

1. Move all the logic from the master to the agent - build a more complex script that does all required work through one monolithic `exec` resource. This may or may not be feasible.
2. Settle for a solution that requires two Puppet runs. Do create a (group of) custom fact(s) that gather the generated file names. Build the manifest in a way that makes sure that all logic that depends on a file name is ignored until the file name has been determined.

Both are likely not ideal.

An ulterior alternative is to rethink your model so that the file names need not be dynamically generated in the first place. I cannot comment on the feasibility without more knowledge of your concrete problem/scenario.

Comment: Thank you again, I ended up writing a custom function using ruby's tempfile class to create the file and return the name.